# anythingSlide change class

Tags: jquery, addclass, anythingslider

I am using anythingSlide and I would like to add an extra function to it,

Basically on the navigation I would like to be able to change a css class for the menu item,

So if you click on menu item 1 it also change the css class of a div using the addclass function, on click it moves the slider and also swaps the a div class.

I am still learning jquery and I just haven't figured it out yet, I am hoping one of you can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want to do, but you could add a callback to add the class you want.

In case you didn't know, the current navigation link has the "cur" class added to it. You could just use that class to do your extra styling.

This code will add the "current" class to the `<li>` surrounding the link:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  onSlideComplete : function(slider){
    slider.$nav  // UL of the navigation list
      .find('li').removeClass('current')
      .find('.cur').parent().addClass('current');
  }
});
```

so your HTML will look something like this:

```
<ul class="thumbNav"> <!-- this is the slider.$nav -->
  <li class="first">
    <a href="#" class="panel1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="current"> <!-- this is the current panel -->
    <a href="#" class="panel2 cur">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="panel3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="panel4">4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="panel5">5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="#" class="panel6">6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Update: Ok, try this... and here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/y4YvF/)

HTML

```
<div id="background" class="bg1"></div>
```

Script

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    onSlideComplete: function(slider){
        // get text, or you could use index()
        var bg = $.trim( slider.$nav.find('.cur').text() );
        // replace entire class
        $('#background').attr('class', 'bg' + bg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick answer! it looks like your on the right track.. il try and explain it a bit better... for each menu item in the slider am going to have a different style class so menu1 = .bg1 menu2 = .bg2 and so on so when u click menu2 it not only adds the cur class the menu but changes the class of another div ie .background to .bg2! .background has nothing to do with the slider it just another div on the page.  hope this helps ??

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Maybe that's more along the lines of what you wanted?

Comment: Cheers Fudgey!! this was just what i was looking for... but one thing this might just be adding it wrong? in the script which gave me i also have the navigationFormatter  which adds txt to the nav some hows its changing the class with the nav names !!

Comment: Hiya, just use this instead `var bg = slider.$nav.find('a').index(slider.$nav.find('.cur')) + 1;`